# Alternative approach for gl.blendFunci function that is missing from WebGL spec

Tags: javascript, webgl, blending

I'm busy converting some OpenGL to WebGL but unable to get a workaround for the [OpenGL function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) `gl.BlendFunci(...)` inside WebGL.

My browser console simply reports:

> gl.blendFunci is not a function

What can I use as an alternative to set different blending functions when drawing to multiple buffers?

Comment: Why would `glBlendFunci` need to exist if there was an alternate way to "set different blending functions when drawing to multiple buffers"?

Comment: @NicolBolas good point. I suppose a better way of asking it would be: "What is the alternative approach?" It would be strange if there is none...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was the WebGL function `gl.blendFuncSeparate(...)`.

Even though it doesn't do exactly what `BlendFunci(...)` does, it still worked for me because it allowed me to set the rgb and alpha blending functions separately. (which is what I was doing with `BlendFunci(...)` anyway)

Found my answer by carefully examining these two files:

https://github.com/tsherif/webgl2examples/blob/master/oit.html

https://github.com/endavid/webGL-tests/blob/master/OIT/oit.js

Answer (score 0):

No version of WebGL has the ability to set different blend functions to different framebuffer render targets. OpenGL ES did not provide this functionality until ES 3.2, nor did desktop GL until 4.0. So it's not unexpected that you can render to multiple targets without having the ability to set different blending parameters for each.

Comment: Ok. What if I draw to two framebuffers the same render but use a different `BlendFunc(...)` for each? Could that give a similar result as to what `BlendFunci(...)` can give?

Comment: You cannot draw to two different FBOs at the same time. There's only one draw_framebuffer binding point.

Comment: What I mean is: bind framebuffer, set blendfunc, draw objects to textureA, bind another framebuffer, set blendfunc, draw objects again but to textureB. Finally send textureA and textureB to shader.